# Allowing Overlapping elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

On one of my pages I have used jquery to animate a navbar button when it is hovered over, however, when i do so it pushes the div below it out of the way and messes up the layout - is it possible to allow the button to animate and intersect the div without moving or affecting its layout?

http://www.omnicraftservers.com/images/problem.png

I am fairly new to web design in general so I may be making some huge mistakes here - please point them out!

The jquery for the list element:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("ul li").mouseenter(function()
  {
    $(this).animate({height:'100px',opacity:'1'},200);
  });
  $("ul li").mouseleave(function()
  {
    $(this).animate({height:'110px',opacity:'0.9'},100);
    $(this).animate({height:'30px',opacity:'0.9'},200);
  });
});
</script>
```

the css for the list element:

```
ul li
{
clear:right;
position:relative;
float:left;
width:100px;
height:auto;
display:inline-block;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-      stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4)));
border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-bottom-left-radius:11px;
border-bottom-right-radius:11px;

text-align:center;
text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
font-size: 20px;

z-index:20;

}
```

and, if this helps, the css for the problematic outer div element:

```
.panel
{
position:relative;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:5px;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(50,50,50,0.7)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)));
border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
width:1148px;
height:185px;
border-radius:11px;
padding:10px;
z-index:0;
}
```

Hope this is enough information for a viable answer - any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: You should post relevant HTML code too. But the behaviour you see is the correct behaviour for elements positionned as realative. You need to place the 'hedaer nav element' in position absolute.

Comment: Sorry for all typos in my previous comment :)

Comment: Works a treat! thanks alot been very useful :)

Comment: How do I credit u man?? No joke this has helped me sooo much!

Comment: Thx, i've posted my comment as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the 'header nav element' in position absolute. This will not affect position of any other elements in the document.